# Unicode Keystroke Characters?

Tags: unicode, keyboard, processing, keystroke

Does unicode have characters in it similar to stuff like the things formed by the `<kbd>` tag in HTML? I want to use it as part of a game to indicate that the user can press a key to perform a certain action, for example:

> Press <kbd>R</kbd> to reset, or <kbd>S</kbd> to open the settings menu.

Are there characters for that?  I don't need anything fancy like <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Tab ⇆</kbd>, single-letter keys are plenty.  I am looking for something that would work somewhat like the [Enclosed Alphanumerics](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2460.pdf) subrange.

If there are characters for that, where could I find a page describing them? All the google searches I tried turned only turned up "unicode character keyboard shortcuts" stuff.

If there are not characters for that, how can I display something like that as part of (or at least in line with) a text string in Processing 2.0.1?

Comment: This is likely outside the remit of the Unicode standard. The standard notes: _"The Unicode Standard does not define glyph images. That is, the standard defines how characters are interpreted, not how glyphs are rendered. Ultimately, the software or hardware rendering engine of a computer is responsible for the appearance of the characters on the screen. The Unicode Standard does not specify the precise shape, size, or orientation of on-screen characters."_ You can find the code point charts [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

Comment: @McDowell Why do they have the [Enclosed Alphanumerics](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2460.pdf), then?

Comment: @AJMansfield; Most of [them](http://goo.gl/6PHX25) are legacy ([1.1 and 3.2](http://goo.gl/LscGrO)): "_There are a large number of compatibility symbols in the Unicode Standard which consist either of letters or numbers enclosed in some graphic element, or which consist of letters or numbers in a square arrangement. Many of these symbols are derived from legacy East Asian character sets, in which such symbols are commonly encoded as elements._" (v6.2, pp. 531).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The rendering referred to is not the default rendering of `kbd`, which simply shows the content in the system’s default monospace font. But e.g. in StackOverflow pages, a style sheet is used to format `kbd` so that it looks like a keycap.)

Somewhat surprisingly, there is a Unicode way to create something that looks like a character in a keycap: enter the character, then immediately COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP [U+20E3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20e3/index.htm).

[Font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20e3/fontsupport.htm) to this character is very limited but contains a few free fonts. Unfortunately, none of them is a sans-serif font, and the character to be shown inside should normally appear in such a font – after all, real keycaps contains very simple shapes for characters, without serifs. And generally, a character and an enclosing mark should be taken from the same font; otherwise they might be incompatible. However, it seems that taking the normal character from the sans-serif font (FreeSans) in [GNU Freefont](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/) and the combining mark from the serif font (FreeSerif) of the same source creates a reasonable presentation:

[image]

I’m afraid it won’t work here in text, but I’ll try: A⃣ .

Whether this works depends on the use of suitable fonts, as mentioned, but also on the rendering software. Programs have been rather bad at displaying combining marks, but there has been some improvement. I tested this in Word 2007, where it works OK, and also on web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) with good results using code like this:

```
<style>
.cap { font-family: FreeSerif; }
.cap span { font-family: FreeSans; }
</style>
<span class="cap"><span>A</span>&#x20e3;</span>
```

It isn’t perfect, when using the fonts mentioned. The character in the cap is not quite centered. Moreover, if I try to use the technique e.g. for the character Å (which is present on normal Nordic keyboards), the ring above A extends out of the cap. You could tweak this by setting the font size of the letter in the cap to, say, 85% of the font size of the combining mark, but then the horizontal position of the letter is even more off.

To summarize, it is *possible* to do such things at the character level, but if you can use other methods, like using a border or a background image for a character, you can probably achieve better rendering.